# Salesforce Community rich text giving invalid page

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, community

I have a Salesforce Community in which I have added a rich text in Template header bottom section.

The rich text includes link where target has been set for some of the VF Pages. When I try to go to the particular navigation tab then all are going fine But for some of the tab i am getting invalid page as a result.

However , When I try to go through the option Go To Community on the top, All the tabs are working great.

Going further , When I go to the login page and try to go to those pages I am getting 'Error: Site under construction'.

I am unable to check the specific reason. Why invalid page is coming when I click on the preview or inside the community builder and getting invalid page. Also when logging in as a user getting Error: Site under construction.

Please assist.

Comment: Turn on the debug logs ? This simply means the VF controller has some issue with community profile .

Comment: One reason why you might get "Site under construction" error is if the VF page is not added to the community or the URL redirect is not properly configured.